# Using ExcelMapper to convert Excel to Object with Index and headerRow is true

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, npoi

I using ExcelMapper to convert Excel to Object. Currently, I need to use mapping with index and the index can be dynamic. This one can be achieve by using AddMapping. However, I cannot get the data if the rowHeader is true.

```
var mapData = getMapData(); // return obj with indexvalue for Name, Title and Author also return HeaderRow 
var excel = new ExcelMapper(@"..\..\..\products.xlsx");
    excel.HeaderRow = mapData.HeaderRow; // issue happen if headerRow is true
    excel.AddMapping<Book>(mapData.Name, p => p.Name);
    excel.AddMapping<Book>(mapData.Title, p => p.Title);
    excel.AddMapping<Book>(mapData.Author, p => p.Author);

    var books = excel.Fetch<Book>().ToList();
```

Comment: I have 1 solution but not the perfect solution which is I just marked header is false and then just remove the first data in the list